# GitHub Actions - Composer failing because of PHP Version constraint

Tags: php, github, composer-php, phpunit, github-actions

I'm trying to get my unit-tests to run via GitHub Actions on a pull_request.

I can see the actions running when I update my PR but the PHP version doesn't update when it tries to composer install my project.

```sh
Command: composer install --no-interaction --no-suggest --no-progress
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~7.3.0 but your PHP version (7.4.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I've tried multiple different workflow files, and this was the one that gave me the most control, but it still seems to be running on php 7.4.

```yaml
name: Run Tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        operating-system: [ubuntu-latest]
        php-versions: ['7.3']

    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php-versions }}
      - uses: php-actions/composer@v2
      - uses: php-actions/phpunit@v8
```

Finally, here is the snippet from my composer json that shows the constraint:

```json
"require": {
    "php": "~7.3.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8"
}
```

Comment: Can also confirm that the shivammathur/setup-php@v2 step is running first, and responds with : `PHP Switched to PHP 7.3.22`

Comment: What makes you think that a completely different action (like `php-actions/composer@v2`) knows which PHP version to use? As far as I see, it uses a different container

Comment: It does? I'm kind of new to github actions. I thought the build set the container, and the steps all ran on the build. Why would composer need to spin up a new container? How would that even work if checkout is what checks out your repo, and you wanted to composer install on your container. What would the point of a composer@v2 action be if it starts a new container and does.... what with it exactly?

Comment: If you write this up as an answer, i'll mark it as complete. I was able to run composer directly rather through an action thanks to your suggestion. Seems a little limiting of the package owners to force a version of PHP when composer has the ability to fix a version! I didn't realise each step was it's own container!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the PHP version for the composer action by adding in your .github/workflows/**YOURACTION.yaml**

```
  - name: Build Composer
    uses: php-actions/composer@v5
    with:
      ssh_key: ${{ secrets.ssh_key }}
      ssh_key_pub: ${{ secrets.ssh_key_pub }}
      php_version: 7.2
```

Notice I did it on the Composer step and not on the **shivammathur/setup-php@v2**
Try removing this step all together, u might not need it at all.

See more here: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/composer-php-actions

Comment: This is a new feature that the module owner put in fairly recently. I spoke with him on reddit a few months ago and he confirmed you can now do this! Great news :)